# weired result from shared_ptr leak test code

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I expected test1.cpp and test2.cpp emit similar result.
same print each run because there are no memory leak..
but It does not. I dont know why.
would you please let me know what it make to understand this situation.

test1.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

class Class {
public:
    shared_ptr<int> value1;
    shared_ptr<int> value2;
    Class() {};
};

int main() {
    char pause;
    while (true) {
        shared_ptr<Class>cls(new Class());
        cout << cls.get() << endl;
        cin >> pause;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

my result

```
0x94b5a10
1
0x94b5a28
1
0x94b5a10
1
0x94b5a28
1
0x94b5a10
```

test2.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

class Class {
public:
    int value1;
    int value2;
    Class() {};
};

int main() {
    char pause;
    while (true) {
        shared_ptr<Class>cls(new Class());
        cout << cls.get() << endl;
        cin >> pause;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

my result

```
0x91baa10
1
0x91baa10
1
0x91baa10
1
0x91baa10
1
0x91baa10
```

test3.cpp - this is most weired result..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

class Class {
public:
    shared_ptr<int> value1;
    shared_ptr<int> value2;
    shared_ptr<int> value3;
    Class() {};
};

int main() {
    char pause;
    while (true) {
        shared_ptr<Class>cls(new Class());
        cout << cls.get() << endl;
        cin >> pause;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

my result

```
0x826ba10
1
0x826ba10
1
0x826ba10
1
0x826ba10
1
0x826ba10
```

Comment: Both is valid behavior. Can you explain what you *expected* and why you think the other one is not ok?

Comment: https://ghostbin.com/paste/sft4q this is what i expected. sorry for link. stackoverflow system sucks.

Comment: You could/should have just edited your question and put your reasoning there. StackOverflow is not a forum.

Comment: @drescherjm I see. thanks

Answer (score 2):

What you are printing are the addresses of the Class (bad name) objects.

In the second case, your Class object gets freed when the shared_ptr goes out of scope and a new one is allocated in the same memory location. Which is OK.

In the first case, for some reason, a different address is picked for the new Class object. Empirically it must have something to do with the other allocations and deallocations that were made. Without looking at the internal logic of the allocator, you won't get a much more precise answer than that.

And, in any case, you should definitely not rely on the addresses following any type of logic. You should simply not care.

Answer (score 0):

In each loop a new **local variable** shared_ptrcls is created and the memory for the object is allocated **dynamically**. When one loop ends, the old object is **deleted automatically**, then the new loop will create a new object and it does not have to have the same address as the old one in last loop since it is totally new. Both results are normal and both situations can happen.

Answer (score 0):

problem solved. what I expected is that every local object will be deleted at the end of while loop(in this case test4.cpp at the end of test function). but It does not.

test4.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

class Class {
public:
    shared_ptr<int> value1;
    shared_ptr<int> value2;
    Class() {};
};

char test() {
  char pause;
  shared_ptr<Class>cls(new Class());
  cout << cls.get() << endl;
  cin >> pause;
  return pause;
}

int main() {
    while (true) {
      if ('q' == test()) break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

test result

```
root@real:~# ltrace -C ./test
__libc_start_main(0x8048d2f, 1, 0xffffd4c4, 0x8048fc0 <unfinished ...>
std::ios_base::Init::Init()(0x804b1d9, 0x4a00, 0xf7c81dc8, 0xf7ffb000) = 0xf7fbde14
__cxa_atexit(0x8048920, 0x804b1d9, 0x804b05c, 0xf7ffb000)    = 0
operator new(unsigned int)(16, 0xffffd4c4, 0xf7fb608c, 0x8048d69) = 0x8050a10
operator new(unsigned int)(16, 0xffffd4c4, 0xf7fb608c, 0x8048d69) = 0x8050a28
std::ostream& std::ostream::_M_insert<void const*>(void const*)(0x804b120, 0x8050a10, 0xf7fb608c, 0x8048d69) = 0x804b120
std::ostream::put(char)(0x804b120, 10, 0xf7fb608c, 0x8048d690x8050a10
) = 0x804b120
std::ostream::flush()(0x804b120, 10, 0xf7fb608c, 0x8048d69)  = 0x804b120
std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator>><char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char&)(0x804b060, 0xffffd3f3, 0xf7fb608c, 0x8048d691
) = 0x804b060
operator delete(void*, unsigned int)(0x8050a10, 16, 0xf7f26f0b, 0xf7fbd660) = 0
operator delete(void*, unsigned int)(0x8050a28, 16, 0xf7f26f0b, 0xf7fbd660) = 0x8050a08
operator new(unsigned int)(16, 0xffffd3f3, 0xf7fb608c, 0x8048d69) = 0x8050a28
operator new(unsigned int)(16, 0xffffd3f3, 0xf7fb608c, 0x8048d69) = 0x8050a10
std::ostream& std::ostream::_M_insert<void const*>(void const*)(0x804b120, 0x8050a28, 0xf7fb608c, 0x8048d69) = 0x804b120
std::ostream::put(char)(0x804b120, 10, 0xf7fb608c, 0x8048d690x8050a28
) = 0x804b120
std::ostream::flush()(0x804b120, 10, 0xf7fb608c, 0x8048d69)  = 0x804b120
std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator>><char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char&)(0x804b060, 0xffffd3f3, 0xf7fb608c, 0x8048d69q
) = 0x804b060
operator delete(void*, unsigned int)(0x8050a28, 16, 0xf7f26f0b, 0xf7fbd660) = 0
operator delete(void*, unsigned int)(0x8050a10, 16, 0xf7f26f0b, 0xf7fbd660) = 0x8050a20
std::ios_base::Init::~Init()(0x804b1d9, 0, 0, 0xf7ca38d7)    = 0xf7fbc5c0
+++ exited (status 0) +++
```